# How to expose a URL to third parties using ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am new to ASP.NET Web API.
Is there is way to expose a URL to third parties using asp.net web API .
where in third parties can post data into the URL and we can process the data.

what i have figured out so far is that using `HttpClient` and `WebClient` class we can GET/Post data from Rest services but no clue on exposing URL.

Is this possible in ASP.NET Web APIs ?or do we need to look into web/wcf services.

any hint/help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is possible. When you create a Web api, enable CORS and you are good to go.

Comment: Check out this article:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#allowed-origins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebAPI` is exactly made for *HTTP services* where this services can be consumed by any third party client/server (mobile devices, servers, web browsers). I'm not sure what you mean by "exposing url" but once your `WebAPI` project runs and is reachable it can be consumed by third parties.

Also, just using the `WebAPI` doesn't mean the project becomes automatically `RESTful`. It is up to you to make it behave in a RESTful way (through data shaping etc.). [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) means Representational state transfer and is an architectural style.

In terms of `CORS`, this has **nothing** to do with `WebAPI` itself. CORS stands for [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)  and is used when your `WebAPI` is consumed by `AJAX` (JavaScript). Which is quite common but it doesn't mean that by enabling `CORS` your web service becomes reachable by third parties. You must first define who will consume your `WebAPI`. If it will be (also) a web browser through the `AJAX` then yes, `CORS` needs to be implemented because web browsers enforce the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Also, don't forget about the security. If your `WebAPI` is accessible only to authorized clients(users) then you need to introduce some security token services ([OAuth](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)), where your HTTP requests would bear a token to make a request for an authorized resource.

Here are docs http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview

Comment: Thanks @Ivan .Exposing URL ,I meant that it has to be consumed by third parties where in they can post back the data and we can process that data further.The data format of post will be in JSON. So can we use CORS or need to do something different?I am wondering about  how to handle the post data .do we need to decorate it with some methods?

Comment: @TechnoSavvy As said, `CORS` is really just a web browser thing. Use `CORS` only if your web api service will be used by any JavaScript application  (angular, jquery etc.) from a different domain. In terms of `post` method, there's nothing particular about this. Your web method just needs to be decorated by `[HttpPost]` decorator. The same with `JSON`. You just always must ensure that request's content type is properly set to `application/json`. Btw. Welcome to SO.